# Deadlock in python single lane bridge implementation

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7, deadlock, semaphore

So I'm trying to learn more about how to use semaphores for synchronization in python.  I have a set up that I feel like should be working but I keep getting deadlock.  This is the classic single lane bridge problem where any number of cars can be going as long as they are going in the same direction.  I'm not as worried about starvation, I know that if there's an infinite stream from one direction then the other will starve.  I just want to get this working with semaphores.  I feel pretty strongly that this should be working, maybe it's a python thing?  I feel like acquiring the semaphore should block if the resource (bridge) isn't available but it doesn't seem to be working like that. Thank you in advance for any input!

```
class OneLaneBridge(object):
"""
A one-lane bridge allows multiple cars to pass in either direction, but at any
point in time, all cars on the bridge must be going in the same direction.

Cars wishing to cross should call the cross function, once they have crossed
they should call finished()
"""

def __init__(self):
    self.dir = -1
    self.bridge_access = Semaphore()
    self.cars_on_bridge = 0
    self.mutex = Semaphore()


def cross(self,direction):
    """wait for permission to cross the bridge.  direction should be either
    north (0) or south (1)."""

    self.mutex.acquire()
    if(self.dir == -1): #direction has been reset
        self.dir = direction

    if(direction == self.dir): #cars already going this direction
        if(self.cars_on_bridge == 0): #first car in this direction acquires lock
            self.bridge_access.acquire()
        #there's now another car on the bridge
        self.cars_on_bridge += 1
    else:
        #block the car and add it to waiting queue (this is how semaphores work?)
        self.bridge_access.acquire()

    self.mutex.release()

def finished(self,direction):
   self.mutex.acquire()
   self.cars_on_bridge -= 1 #car is now off the bridge
   if(self.cars_on_bridge == 0): #no more cars on bridge so release access
       self.bridge_access.release()
       self.dir = -1 #reset the direction so the next car will dictate the direction

   self.mutex.release()
```

EDIT:

The problem was in the cross() method as was rightly pointed out.  The issue was that the mutex wasn't being released leading to deadlock, and that once the mutex was released and the cars weren't blocked anymore, they weren't being properly handled like the others.  Here is the new cross method with most of the changes being in the else block:

```
def cross(self,direction):
    """wait for permission to cross the bridge.  direction should be either
    north (0) or south (1)."""

    self.mutex.acquire()
    if(self.dir == -1):
        self.dir = direction

    if(direction == self.dir):
        if(self.cars_on_bridge == 0):
            self.bridge_access.acquire()
        self.cars_on_bridge += 1
    else:
        self.mutex.release()
        self.bridge_access.acquire()
        self.mutex.acquire()
        self.cars_on_bridge += 1
        self.dir = direction
        self.mutex.release()

    self.mutex.release()
```

Comment: Consider this.A car is going in direction `1`.Now there are three enter requests with direction `2`.All 3 will be blocked at `self.bridge_access.acquire()`.Now when the bridge goes empty.One of the three will be picked up.Then the other two will still wait for the bridge to go empty even though the direction is same.

Comment: Can you please post the full code or a link to the src code in GitHub?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the a car going the wrong direction blocks in `cross` it will still be holding the mutex and so other threads will deadlock when they attempt to obtain the mutex.

Also once a car going to the wrong direction unblocks in `cross` it still hasn't begun to cross yet. You still need to set the direction and increment the count of cars on the bridge, because you've only done that in case when the car was going the correct direction. If you just release the mutex and return like your code is attempting to do the caller of `cross` will assume that the car has been allowed on to the bridge.

Comment: That makes sense, I can fix that first part.  As for the second part, doesn't release do that in some way?

Comment: `release` just increments the semaphore and unblocks other threads if the count goes from 0 to 1. I'll try to update my answer to be more clear.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I couldn't get it quite right in this set up but what you said is definitely right. I'm going to try maybe two separate semaphores? Like the reader writer problem only with two readers maybe.

Comment: nevermind, figured it out! It all works now thank you very much! I'll edit my original post to show the change